# Актуализация последовательности в PostgreSQL 9 при использовании Eloquent ORM

Tags: postgresql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Если я вставляю часть данных в таблицу PostgreSQL с заданными ID, а потом, начинаю вставлять данные без ID, чтобы срабатывал Sequence - получаю ошибку dublicate key.

Например, предустановленные пользователи приложения. Или роли. А потом пользователь сам может добавить пользователи/роли. Т.е. на первом этапе ID важны, а потом уже не очень.

Проблема решается строчкой кода, типа

```
\DB::select("select setval('users_id_seq', (select max(id) + 1 from users));");
```

но какое-то костыльное решение. Типа, ORM, ORM, чистый SQL, ORM, ORM,...

Может кто-нибудь предложить более изящное решение?

Answer (score 1):

В целом - не привязывайтесь к значениям сиквенса. Зачем вам хардкодить id?

Если по каким-то причинам это невозможно, то зарезервируйте себе какой-нибудь достаточный начальный диапазон и попросите сиквенс стартовать с другого значения сразу при создании схемы базы. Например, по аналогии с id пользователя *nix, первые 1000 - системные:

```
alter sequence some_sequence_name start with 1000;
```